# What's the best way to store grouped key value pairs in a file?

Tags: .net, file-format

Currently I just have a file like this that I manually parse into a Dictionary:

```
str1=Hello
str2=World
```

This is no longer practical for several reasons:

- I need lists of strings that I can access by index
- I want to split the key value pairs into groups

I consider using XML now because:

- Good for key value pairs and groups
- I could use classes and serialize them, eliminating spelling errors

But (assuming I use serialized classes):

- I would have to create a lot of new classes to map the document structure
- Dictionaries need to be cared for specially because the can't usually be serialized

Do you recommend this approach? Should I use the XmlDocument class instead? Is there some other format that has free libraries for .net?

I want to use this for localizing an application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET has pretty solid Resource-based support for [localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163609.aspx), so you might look into that.

If you really want to invent your own resource storage format, I'd suggest you to look more closely at [JSON](http://json.org/) as serialization format (there are plenty of .NET libraries to handle it) or at YAML (not sure if there are decent .NET parsers): they both are much simpler on the eye (if that's what you're after).

Comment: How do you store lists in resources? Are there any issues with mono?

Comment: Not sure about lists. Why would you want to store them in resource files? Neither I know anything about Mono.

Comment: The values should be numbered for use in lists and as enum value names.

Comment: Well, having Value1, Value2, ..., ValueN as keys, you can always for-loop over them and retrieve localized string with call to ResourceManager.GetString()

Comment: The strings should still have a name. I'll probably go with a class with Dictionaries and serialize it to XML or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

A [CSV file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) would be nice and compact.

Comment: How would you do the grouping?

Answer (score 0):

**XmlDocument**

Don’t use XmlDocument unless you absolutely need to. It is optimized for constructing xml not reading it. http://www.mattberther.com/2004/06/16/xmldocument-vs-xpathnavigator/
Use either an XmlReader or an XPathNavigator. If you are reading into classes consider doing a direct serialize with XMLSerializer.

**Xml versus flat file**

Only use XML if you are creating a hierarchy of objects. From your description a simple line by line read of a text file would suffice. You can then split on the first occurrence of “=” and read it into a Dictionary, a List, or some custom structure. It will be faster than XML and easier to maintain.

**Spelling**

I don’t think XML helps you with spelling errors.

**Localization**

Should be done with resource files
Have a look here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Localization.aspx 
or on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization+.net